# Printing with an action

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to execute an action or actionListner method alone with a print action. For example, is it possible to print a bill and mark the print bill as printed by a back bean method without clicking two buttons?

```
<h:commandButton value="Print" actionListener="#{labBillController.markAsPrinted()}" >
    <p:printer target="panelBill" ></p:printer>
</h:commandButton>
```

Both actions of above code are not happening simultaneously. If ajax used , actionListner methos is executed. If non ajux, only printing, but no execution of Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
<h:commandButton value="Print" actionListener="#{labBillController.markAsPrinted()}" >
    <f:ajax execute="@this" />
    <p:printer target="panelBill" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: This works fine. My actual requirement was to list the bills in a datagrid and print the bill of the selected row with the help of the f:setPropertyActionListener, but when I added it within the command button the same issue occurs again.

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne I'm not sure why this is happening to be perfectly honestly. If I were to guess I would say that `p:printer` is "ajaxified" but when you press `h:commandButton` which is not something gets lost in translation. So to avoid this, I ajaxified `h:commandButton`. When you submit the form then all ajax requests will be served in a first come first serve manner (*I think*)

Comment: @BuddhikaAriyaratne In case you might be wondering what I mean by ajaxifying `h:commandButton`, `h:commandButton` by default will call `actionListener` method when you attach `f:ajax` to it and you don't specify an event. So, actionListener gets called first, then `p:printer`